# I think I spider / My English is not the yellow from the egg

Tags: phrases

I'm trying to improve my English skills.
Can I use the phrase "My English is not the yellow from the egg" or "I think I spider" in an English spoken country?

Comment: You can use them but I'm not sure anyone would know what you mean.  The "my English is not the yellow from the egg" sounds like an expression translated from another language but I'm unsure what is meant by that expression.  "I think I spider" is ungrammatical and again, I don't know what is meant by that expression.

Comment: I agree -- both are meaningless.  But you can say them if you wish -- no one will stop you or arrest you.

Comment: It may well be that someone's leg is being pulled.  "I think I spider" and "My English is not a yoke" are (very poor) puns.  (But then, is there any other form of pun?)

Comment: @KristinaLopez These are direct (and wrong!) translations from German. "I think I spider" comes from "Ich glaube ich spinne", which actually means "I think I'm going crazy". The word "spinne" is [the conjugated form of "spinnen"](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-german-verb-spinnen.html), which means to go crazy, but it's also the German word for "spider". Not sure whether this is a mistake or deliberate, in an attempt to be funny (there's [a whole website dedicated to these wrong tranlations](http://ithinkispider.com/))

Comment: @HotLicks The other sentence comes from "Mein Englisch ist nicht das Gelbe vom Ei, aber es geht", literally "My English isn't the yellow of the egg, but it goes". As some have guessed, it means: "My English isn't the best, but it's acceptable". I think a good translation would be "It isn't the cream of the crop". Or, as [Pons](https://en.pons.com/translate/german-english/das+Gelbe+vom+Ei) suggests, "to not be the greatest thing since sliced bread".

Answer (score 1):

Spider is a noun and has never been used as a verb.  ( That doesn't mean that one day it won't become a verb and it may not express what you are trying to express.) Also, as Kristina said above, this may be too literal of a translation of your language to English.

As far as "my English is not the yoke from the egg," it sounds like you are saying that your English is not the best in the world, but I'm only guessing this from context.  I can't think of any equivalent expressions in English that are as poetic as this one.  Most people understand that "My English is not the greatest."  Or "Right now, I can only get by in English." Or "I'm a beginner" would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

If you say, "I think I spider," any native English speaker will think that you said, "I think I spied her," and will be very confused.

Spider can, in fact, be used as a verb, and has several possible meanings:

> 1 [no object] Move in a scuttling manner suggestive of a spider:  ‘a
>   treecreeper spidered head first down the tree trunk’
>
> 1.1Form a pattern suggestive of a spider or its web.
>
> 2 [with object]  Computing  another term for crawl (sense 4 of the
>   verb). ‘when the search engines spider your site they’ll find all of
>   the pages’

but none of these seems likely to be used in the first person.

As for "the yellow from the egg", I've never heard such a phrase, although in cooking you can speak of separating the yolk from the white.

So, no, I doubt you can use either phrase.

Answer (score 0):

I like the picturesque phrase describing your English. And in English, the word *yolk* means the *yellow part of the egg* - you don't have to say *yolk of an egg* because there is no other meaning of the word.
I think it would help if you told us your mother tongue, and then we could perhaps work out what *spider* means to you.

Comment: Actually, the yoke's on you.